# User Helper Method - grabbing users whose ID doesn't match current user ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helpermethods

trying to write a helper method with 3 basic conditions.  adding the 3rd one, which is trying to take the current user out of the results, is resulting in an error.

```
  def male_soccer_players
    return User.where(:gender => "male", :soccer => true, :id != current_user.id)
  end
```

The error is

```
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in this  `:id != current_user.id`
Rails `.where` pass only hash
try

```
def male_soccer_players
  User.where(:gender => "male", :soccer => true).where('id != ?', current_user.id)
end
```

or

```
def male_soccer_players
  User.where('gender = ? and soccer = ? and id != ?', "male", true, current_user.id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a scope?

```
scope :except, ->(user) { where.not(id: user) }
```

And in your case:

```
def male_soccer_players
  User.except(current_user).where(:gender => "male", :soccer => true)
end
```

Optionally, **if you want**, you can take this a step further and create other scopes if reusability is something that interests you:

```
scope :male, -> { where(gender: "male") }
scope :soccer_player, -> { where(soccer: true) }

def male_soccer_players
  User.male.soccer_player.except(current_user)
end
```

Comment: `{ where.not(id: user) }` clean ))

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 def male_soccer_players
        return User.where(:gender => "male", :soccer => true).where("id not != ", current_user.id)
    end
```